# CakePHP returns [object object] in confirm dialog

Tags: javascript, cakephp-2.3

Does anyone have any idea why this happens?

My code below:

```
echo $this->Form->postLink('Excluir', array('action' => 'apagar', $credenciamento['Credenciamento']['id']), array('class' => 'linkbtn') ,array('confirm' => 'Deseja excluir este credenciamento?' ));
```

Code Generated by cake:

```
<a href="#" class="linkbtn" onclick="if (confirm({"confirm":"Deseja excluir este credenciamento?"})) { document.post_52fdf00c73775579079346.submit(); } event.returnValue = false; return false;">Excluir</a>
```

When i try to delete any record through this link, he works, but the message returned in dialog box is just:

[object object]

OK button and Cancel button

I used Jquery in this project too, but dialog boxes generated by my scripts returns correctly.

Comment: Are you sure that code gives that result? `onclick="if (confirm({"` should throw an error because the JavaScript gets cut off by the second `"`.

Comment: `confirm()` expects a plain string.

Comment: Copyed as HTML through google chrome...

`<a href="#" class="linkbtn" onclick="if (confirm({&quot;confirm&quot;:&quot;Deseja excluir este credenciamento?&quot;})) { document.post_52fdf00c73775579079346.submit(); } event.returnValue = false; return false;">Excluir</a>`

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer:

```
echo $this->Form->postLink('Excluir credenciamento', array('action' => 'apagar', $credenciamento['Credenciamento']['id']), array('confirm' => 'Deseja excluir este credenciamento?','class' => 'linkbtn'));
```

The order of parameters in array...